# Difference between SignedExtension default behavior vs. actual behavior (expand_outer_validate_unsigned)

Tags: signed-extensions, validation, unsigned

We're trying to understand the signed transaction vs. unsigned transaction lifecycle, and what ensure_signed *actually* does for you.

What it seemed was, if you submitted an unsigned transaction to our pallet that it would put the failed txn in the block because it should fail `ensure_signed` with `BadOrigin`, correct?  Just like any other failure inside of an extrinsic. IF you assume this, then it's fine for Pays::Yes txns.

However in Pays::No txns, one would think submitting unsigned txns would be an attack vector. Yet running our chain locally, we can submit unsigned txns all day long, and they will never be put in a block as a failed transaction, it will be invalid, because it reaches, (we think) [this generated/macro code in `validate_unsigned`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8fb4138d73ad88a19331c30c36ba91796c5846e1/frame/support/procedural/src/construct_runtime/expand/unsigned.rs#L84), displaying `UnknownTransaction::NoUnsignedValidator` in the Polkadot dashboard, without our having to do anything extra.

And in fact if we call this extrinsic using Sudo, it fails with `BadOrigin`, and the failed transaction is included in a block...so I guess we shouldn't DoS ourselves.

So next, SignedExtension's default validate_unsigned has [something very different](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8fb4138d73ad88a19331c30c36ba91796c5846e1/primitives/runtime/src/traits.rs#L1120):

```rs
fn validate_unsigned(
    _call: &Self::Call,
    _info: &DispatchInfoOf<Self::Call>,
    _len: usize,
) -> TransactionValidity {
    Ok(ValidTransaction::default())
}
```

Basically it seems that unsigned transactions are not calling the above default implementation, but instead the first one which is automagically generated for pallets regardless of whether they have a SignedExtension implemented. Following the code, this `expand_outer_validate_unsigned` function is called (probably self-evident by now) in construct_runtime.

Question is what is the use of the default for the trait? Are we correct in thinking that unsigned transactions are default rejected before getting to the extrinsic code, unless you explicitly allow them?  What is then the real purpose of ensure_signed?  We were thinking it would also prevent Root from executing such a transaction.

Lastly, for something called **Signed**Extension, why is there a validate_unsigned function at all? The trait name would seem to imply it's really just for signed transactions.

Answer (score 3):

The lifecycle of a extrinsic validation is the following:

1. The transaction pool call the Runtime API [`validate_transaction`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a6da808575fe403ab2bd7f6cd009896cdc6fd71a/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1839-L1847) method
2. There, [`validate_transaction`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a6da808575fe403ab2bd7f6cd009896cdc6fd71a/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L538-L570) from the `Executive` pallet is called. `uxt` is of type `Block::Extrinsic`, which for the default substrate runtime equals to `UncheckedExtrinsic` (from [this line](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a6da808575fe403ab2bd7f6cd009896cdc6fd71a/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1688) and [this one](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a6da808575fe403ab2bd7f6cd009896cdc6fd71a/primitives/runtime/src/generic/block.rs#L100).
3. In `Executive::validate_transaction`, after calculating `encoded_len`, it [`check()`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a6da808575fe403ab2bd7f6cd009896cdc6fd71a/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L559) the `UncheckExtrinsic`. At this point, `UncheckExtrinsic` can be either a signed or unsigned extrinsic, we do not know yet.
4. In the [`check()`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a6da808575fe403ab2bd7f6cd009896cdc6fd71a/primitives/runtime/src/generic/unchecked_extrinsic.rs#L149-L164) method for the generic `UncheckedExtrinsic` is where is checked if the extrinsic is signed or not. In both cases, a `CheckedExtrinsic` is return. If signed, the `signed` attribute will contain the signature information, if unsigned, the `signed` attribute will be set to `None`. That field in the `CheckedExtrinsic` is the one that differentiate between a signed and an unsigned extrinsic.
5. Next action in `Executive:validate_transaction` is to get the [`dispatch_info`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a6da808575fe403ab2bd7f6cd009896cdc6fd71a/primitives/runtime/src/generic/unchecked_extrinsic.rs#L149-L164) from the previously returned `CheckedExtrinsic`. That happens [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a6da808575fe403ab2bd7f6cd009896cdc6fd71a/frame/support/procedural/src/pallet/expand/call.rs#L245-L275) returning the `DispatchInfo` struct.
6. Finally, the `CheckedExtrinsic` is [validated](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a6da808575fe403ab2bd7f6cd009896cdc6fd71a/frame/executive/src/lib.rs#L568). If we pay attention to its [method](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/a6da808575fe403ab2bd7f6cd009896cdc6fd71a/primitives/runtime/src/generic/checked_extrinsic.rs#L52-L67), we can see how depending on its `signed` attribute (if it exists or `None`), a different method will be called from its type `Extra`. If it exists (signed tx), it calls `Extra::validate`, if not (unsigned tx), it calls `Extra::validate_unsigned` and `U::validate_unsigned`. Here is where signed and unsigned extrinsic validation flow diverge.

`ensure_signed` prevents unsigned extrinsic to execute your dispatchable. I still would need to investigate why all your unsigned transactions are failing.

It is true that `SignedExtension` name might be a bit misleading since both, signed & unsigned extrinsics go through them.

Comment: Excellent summary.  However, the last bit though doesn't seem to be complete.  Only signed transactions use all the `SignedExtension` extras: `check_{non_zero_sender, mortality, nonce, genesis, tx_version, spec_version, weight}`.  Whereas unsigned transactions only use the `SignedExtension` `check_weight`.  Correct?

Answer (score 1):

I think @robert-la-ferla and I may have answered the question that I had originally.  To recap, for an `UnsignedExtension`, looking at [primitives/runtime/src/generic/checked_exstrinsic#validate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8fb4138d73ad88a19331c30c36ba91796c5846e1/primitives/runtime/src/generic/checked_extrinsic.rs#L63), the call of `Extra::validate_unsigned` is where the `SignedExtra` list `validate_unsigned` functions would be called.  Only `check_weights` of the signed extensions we are using has `validate_unsigned` implemented.  For all other pallets, the `SignedExtrinsic` default `validate_unsigned` is called - which returns `Ok(...)`

To expand on your #6 point, @ignacio-palacios, as you point out the next line is the `U::validate_unsigned` and we believe that this calls that generated in `construct_runtime.rs` (by calling [`expand_outer_validate_unsigned`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/8fb4138d73ad88a19331c30c36ba91796c5846e1/frame/support/procedural/src/construct_runtime/expand/unsigned.rs#L24)), where, if the pallet whose function is being called implements `validate_unsigned`, that is called, otherwise it returns `UnknownTransaction::NoUnsignedValidator`.  In short we think line 63 passes for unsigned transactions and goes on to fail in line 64.

I believe this means by default no pallet will accept unsigned extrinsics, and to accept one must implement `validate_unsigned` in the pallet and do whatever checks are needed to allow a given unsigned extrinsic call.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.